# Add trigger to AWS Lambda functions via Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Following: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function
and some digging online, it seems there is no way to add a trigger to the lambda functions via `lambda function` resource in tf. In my case: Create any object on a specific S3 bucket that triggers the lambda function.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Use a [`s3_bucket_notification`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_notification) - that is not a workaround, that is the way it is supposed to work. For a lot of other invocation configs use [`lambda_event_source_mapping`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping).

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_notification), these are the resources you need to create the lambda function and the **S3 trigger**:

```
 resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.func.arn
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "func" {
  filename      = "your-function.zip"
  function_name = "example_lambda_name"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler       = "exports.example"
  runtime       = "go1.x"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "your-bucket-name"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.func.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "AWSLogs/"
    filter_suffix       = ".log"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this case or any other external source (like an EventBridge Rule, SNS etc) in order to have the permission to access the Lambda function you can depend on this TF resource :  `aws_lambda_permission`.

How to use this in relation with various other sources is clearly explained over here - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission.html

Hope it helps!